# Why can I omit the constructor when referring to newtype wrapped number types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

On page 321 of *Real World Haskell*

There are these codes,

...

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype AInt = A { unA::Int }
    deriving (Show, Eq, Num)

instance Monoid AInt where
    mempty = 0
```

My confusion is why it is

```
mempty = 0
```

but not

```
mempty = A 0
```

?

---

I also noticed that both

```
ghci> 0 :: AInt
```

and

```
ghci> A 0 :: AInt
```

give me the same response

```
A { unA = 0 }
```

Would someone please tell me what is the difference between theses two?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick here is with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension. In particular, this lets us derive *any* class for a `newtype` as long as the underlying type is an instance. All this does is copy over the instance from the old type to the new type.

In this particular case, `AInt` derives `Num`. This means that `AInt` is an instance of `Num` using the same code as `Int` (with everything wrapped in `A` constructors as appropriate). This includes `Int`'s `fromInteger` function.

The `fromInteger` function is defined in terms of `Int`'s `fromInteger`, looking something like this:

```
fromInteger i = A (fromInteger i)
```

Since `0` is polymorphic--it has the type `0 :: Num a => a`--it's a valid constant for *any* type in `Num`. Thanks to the newtype deriving, this includes `AInt`, using the `fromInteger` function above. This means there is really no difference between `0 :: AInt` an `A 0 :: AInt`.

Comment: So it is the same reason that we can do both `1::Float` and `1::Int` ?

Comment: @Znatz: Yep. Since `AInt` is in `Num`, it can use the literals just like `Float`, `Int` and a ton of other types.

Answer (score 12):

Numeric literals like `0` are overloaded and have the type `0 :: Num a => a`, which means that they can be any type for which there is a `Num` instance, depending on the context. This happens via the `fromInteger` function in the `Num` type class, so when you type `0` it is treated as if you'd written `fromInteger 0`.

By using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, GHC has (effectively<sup>1</sup>) written a `Num` instance for your class looking something like this:

```
instance Num AInt where
  fromInteger n = A (fromInteger n)
  ...
```

So when you write `0 :: AInt`, this expands to `fromInteger 0 :: AInt` which is (by the definition above) equal to `A (fromInteger 0)` which is the same as if you had written `A 0`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` doesn't actually write a new intance. It just performs the necessary casts to use the existing one.</sub>

Comment: It actually does write a new instance, I'm told. The tricky bit is that superclass instances might not be GND derived, which would invalidate the superclass instance pointers. That is, you could, I believe, write `instance Eq Foo where ... ; deriving instance Ord Foo`. To avoid running into trouble in these cases, I'm told GHC builds new dictionaries, but reuses the members.